# Angular ChartJs does not show Data for multiple Charts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio, chart.js

I'm trying to get in `Angular` multiple Charts on One Page. I saw an Example with the `ViewChildren`:

```
const baseConfig: Chart.ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'pie',
  options: {
    responsive: true,
  }
};

@ViewChildren('chart', { read: ElementRef }) chartElementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  chartData: Chart.ChartData[] = [
    {
      labels: ['1500', '1600', '1700', '1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000],
        borderColor: 'red',
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    {
      labels: ['1500', '1600', '1700', '1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000].reverse(),
        borderColor: 'blue',
        fill: false
      }]
    }
  ];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.charts = this.chartElementRefs.map((chartElementRef, index) => {
      const config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, { data: this.chartData[index] 
    });
    console.log(chartElementRef);
    return new Chart(chartElementRef.nativeElement, config);
  });
}
```

and I tried to get that in a method:

```
@ViewChildren('chart', { read: ElementRef }) chartElementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
chartData: Chart.ChartData[] = []

createChartData(){
  var arrayChart: any = []
  console.log('number of charts', this.numberOfCharts);

  for (var i = 0; i < this.numberOfCharts; i++){
    var pie = {
      labels: ["Disks", "Mgmt", "Hardware", "FC", "Vols&Pols"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        backgroundColor: ["#008000", "#008000", "#008000", "#008000", "#008000"]
      }]
    }
    arrayChart.push(pie);
  }
  this.chartData= arrayChart;
  this.charts = this.chartElementRefs.map((chartElementRef, index) => {
    const config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, { data: this.chartData[index] 
  });
  console.log(chartElementRef);
  return new Chart(chartElementRef.nativeElement, config);
  });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of chartData">
    <canvas #chart></canvas>
</div>
```

and called the method in `ngAfterViewInit()`, but that won't work... it shows only empty place. But if I do that like the Example, then it will show 2 Pie Charts. Does anyone know why?

**EDIT**

I want to do it in a method to subscribe from the Service

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of chartData">
    <canvas #chart></canvas>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, ElementRef, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

const baseConfig: Chart.ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'pie',
  options: {
    responsive: true,
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren('chart', { read: ElementRef }) chartElementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  chartData: Chart.ChartData[] = [
    {
      labels: ['1500', '1600', '1700', '1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000],
        borderColor: 'red',
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    {
      labels: ['1500', '1600', '1700', '1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [86, 378, 106, 306, 507, 111, 133, 221, 783, 5000].reverse(),
        borderColor: 'blue',
        fill: false
      }]
    }
  ];

  charts: Chart[] = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.charts = this.chartElementRefs.map((chartElementRef, index) => {
      const config = Object.assign({}, baseConfig, { data: this.chartData[index] });

      return new Chart(chartElementRef.nativeElement, config);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That is the same example... I want to make it in a method to subscribe the data from service